# How to read and change ACL of active directory objects using c#

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, exchange-server-2010

I need to find users who has permission *Send As* on different user object. It is the permission we can see in *Security tab* of User in ADUC using C# or the permission we can get using PowerShell cmdlet `Get-ADPermission`.

I need to get this information using C# and I can't use the `System.Management.Automation` assembly.

I use Windows 2008 R2 for domain controller and Exchange 2010.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Why can't you use `System.Management.Automation` ?

Comment: Yes, it possible to use System.Management.Automation, but it's work slowly. I found one very nice book, to work vith directoryService, and found solution. I'll add it later. The book is The .NET Developer's Guide to Directory Services Programming 
By Joe Kaplan, Ryan Dunn